# Check IF String1 = String2 (with just 1 typo) in postgresql (fuzzymatch & levenshtein unavailable)

Tags: postgresql, string-matching

I need to check if an e-mail address matches another with the possible exception of one typo (e.g. "hormail" instead of "hotmail", a letter missing, or an extra letter).

It's a postgresql (version 9.1.4) query, and neither fuzzymatch nor levenshtein is available.

Comment: PostgreSQL version? I doubt you can do this reasonably efficiently in SQL or PL/PgSQL. They're just not great at string manipulation.

Comment: Do you need to handle transpositions, like `teh` instead of `the` ? Only single-character substitutions like `tje` instead of `the`? Insertions like `thje`? Omissions like `te` ? How strict is the "one typo" rule and what, exactly, does "one typo" mean? This is a fairly ideal case for the [pg_tgrm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) module, but I'm guessing you can't use it either. This seems like a very painful thing to do in the DB without any extensions.

Comment: Ideally, it would handle all the above. PostgreSQL version is 9.1.4 and unfortunately I can't use any extensions.

Comment: And the second part of my question? How strict is the "one typo" rule and what *exactly* does "one typo" mean? At least you're on a modern version, even if crippled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starting point. It's a function that breaks both emails down into (char-pos, char) pairs, then finds pairs that're mismatched between the two inputs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_diffs(
    email1 IN text, email2 IN text, 
    chnum OUT integer, ch OUT text, fromwhich OUT integer
) 
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH 
        e1chars AS (
            SELECT generate_series(0, length($1) -1 ) AS chpos, regexp_split_to_table($1,'') ch
        ),
        e2chars AS (
            SELECT generate_series(0, length($2) - 1) AS chpos, regexp_split_to_table($2,'') ch
        ),
        only_in_e1chars AS (
            SELECT * FROM e1chars EXCEPT SELECT * FROM e2chars
        ),
        only_in_e2chars AS (
            SELECT * FROM e2chars EXCEPT SELECT * FROM e1chars
        ),
        mismatched_pairs AS (
            SELECT *, 1 FROM only_in_e1chars UNION SELECT *, 2 FROM only_in_e2chars
        )
    SELECT * FROM mismatched_pairs;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

Results look like this:

```
regress=# SELECT * FROM email_diffs('fred@bo','fred@bob');
 chnum | ch | fromwhich 
-------+----+-----------
     7 | b  |         2
(1 row)

regress=# SELECT * FROM email_diffs('fred@bob','fred@bbo');
 chnum | ch | fromwhich 
-------+----+-----------
     6 | b  |         2
     6 | o  |         1
     7 | b  |         1
     7 | o  |         2
(4 rows)
```

You should be able to call this with another CTE that tests for each of the errors you are interested in, or just extend the CTE in that main function with additional clauses to test for each case and return a verdict.

Exactly how to do that will depend on the specifics of the rules you must test and how strict you have to be about detecting exactly one typo. You haven't specified that.

---

You might have noticed the odd-looking use of a SELECT without a FROM clause in `e1chars` and `e2chars`, where two functions are called in the SELECT list. This is a very strange PostgreSQL extension to SQL that you really shouldn't generally use, as results are often not what you expect. PostgreSQL will support the SQL-standard `LATERAL` syntax in 9.3, and that should be used in preference.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fuzzystrmatch and/or pg_trgm Postgres extensions. You can enable these by running:

```
$ psql mydb
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

You can then perform queries like these:

```
mydb=# SELECT email from Users where email % 'hormail' or difference(email, 'hormail') > 2;
```